# Using a count as a percentage to determine results

Tags: sql

I need to compare the StatusID's of a job in the last 12 hours. If the value is over 50%, an alert is created.

```
select StatusID, count(statusid) as [count]
from job nolock 
where jobtypeid = 5033 
    and ModifiedOn > CONVERT(datetime,dateadd(hh,-12,getdate()),104)
group by statusid
order by 1 desc
```

[image: StatusIDCount]

This gives me my results, but I need it as part of:

```
CASE WHEN "Count(StatusID = 5 > 50%)" THEN ''GREEN'' ELSE ''RED''
```

How can I turn the top `select` into a `Case`?

Comment: What is the denominator in your example above? And you only care about statusID 5? What about statusID 4?

Comment: 4 is good runs, 5 is bad runs, so 50% of the total of all possible StatusID's (1-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT jobtypeid,  StatusID,
       CASE WHEN StatusID=5 AND 
                 CNT*1.0 /SUM(CNT) OVER (PARTITION BY jobtypeid)>0.5 
            THEN 'RED' ELSE 'GREEN'
       END AS Status5Result
  FROM
  (
    SELECT jobtypeid,  StatusID, 
       COUNT(*) CNT
    From job 
    WHERE jobtypeid = 5033 AND
          ModifiedOn > CONVERT(datetime,dateadd(hh,-12,getdate()),104)
    GROUP BY jobtypeid,  StatusID
  ) T
ORDER BY StatusID
```

See a *[**demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Bksbk4oo)*.

The subquery finds the count for each StatusID within the jobtypeid, and the main query uses a sum window function to find the sum of all StatusID count within a jobtypeid.

Answer (score 0):

Please explain how you are going to determine the percentage?
If you just want to check `count(statusid)>50` then:

```
select StatusID, count(statusid) as [count], (case when count(statusid)>50 then 'GREEN' else 'RED' end)
from job nolock 
where jobtypeid = 5033 
    and ModifiedOn > CONVERT(datetime,dateadd(hh,-12,getdate()),104)
group by statusid
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: A count of all possible StatusID's (1-7). If 50% of that count is `StatusID = 5`, `then 'RED'`